# One IP address to be allowed only once in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

we have to build a functionality in asp.net and c# which in a online survey one ip address will only be allowed to attend the survey once? how can we achieve this?

Comment: I believe it is bad idea... But please clarify your question. It is not clear what your problem is currently - storing requesting IP in a database should not be that hard...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a user's client IP address in ASP.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735350/how-to-get-a-users-client-ip-address-in-asp-net)

Comment: @User1673394, please check the above question for more details

Comment: Note that various ISP use NAT, so their users are all behind few IP Addresses. Cellular Networks nearly always use NAT.

Comment: I think using only IP address is bad idea as their could be many user using a single proxy server and having same IP address. A combination of IP address and cookie could be a solution, but again there is no bullet proof solution.

Comment: I would look into browser fingerprinting instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make sure a user can only vote once on an ASP.NET poll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/522871/how-to-make-sure-a-user-can-only-vote-once-on-an-asp-net-poll)

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get IP

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress; 
or 
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
or
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
```

Store some where in database..now for every time on Request for survey you can lookup in database that it is exist or not